# Is there a way to use TextToColumns for comma separation with only 2 values?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA `TextToColumns` in order to split comma separated values into their own columns, however when there's only 2 values it changes the `comma` to `dot` and doesn't split the value into columns.

I have tried changing the comma separation value, but I have other projects that are dependent on the use of comma for this particular point.
I dont fully understand the `TextToColumns` code, so modifying it is a bit of a challenge.

```
Sheets("rapport").Range("N4:N" & rowCount).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N4"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
            Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
            ), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array _
            (20, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

N contains following example values:

```
1,2,3
1,2
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3
1,2
```

I expect the following result:

```
1 - 2 - 3
1 - 2
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
1 - 2 - 3
1 - 2
```

I get the following result: 
(1.2 is in the same column and does't get split)

```
1 - 2 - 3
1.2
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
1 - 2 - 3
1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your windows system settings.

If the system settings is using the comma as a decimal separator excel will consider (1,2) as a one number and will not split it. and this confusion is only when there is one comma in your example.